# Win 2016 - I thought Cumulative Updates package all updates from the past

Tags: windows-server-2016

Installed fresh Windows 2016 from ISO (VLSC) and it’s making me download 2018-04, 2018-05, 2018-09, 2018-11 Cumulative Updates.

I thought Microsoft was changing this to 1 update after fresh install to avoid installing multiple updates to “catch up”?

Any idea why this is happening? Also - if I have the same computer specs on both, why does one install 2018-04 and the other doesn’t?

KB4093137 is the 2018-04 Update that installed on one and not the other. Same hardware specs.

Comment: Do both machines have the same version of Windows 10.  In order to determine which version you have installed, use winver, and update your question with the relevant information required to answer your question.  When you update your question, provide us the actual KBs associated with the patches, there is a reason this is happening.

Comment: Microsoft has never indicated you would only receive a single cumulative update through Windows Update. You would need to download the current cumulative update yourself to accomplish that task.

Comment: Oh maybe I misunderstood how they handle CU’s then. I thought Windows would just pull the latest one to catch up from all priors. If I have to manually install the first one, that’s fine. I was thinking Windows would figure that out.

Comment: Yes I’m using the same iso file from VLSC.

Comment: You have changed this question significantly by making it about Windows Server 2016 instead of Windows 10.  There are multiple April 2018 cumulative updates, I really wanted a screenshot of your Windows Update, to better understand what actually is happening. I really need the build information in order to answer this question, I cannot answer it, without that infomration.

Comment: OS Build is 14393.2639 and OS Version 1607. Standard Edition.

Comment: If it helps any, it’s Supermicro SSG-2029P-ACR24H

Comment: https://ibb.co/F7jfvXp

Comment: Here is what I suspect happened.  There were numerous Servicing stack updates released since the ISO was created, these updates are sometimes necessary to install a given cumulative update, but you did skip several months worth of cumulative updates.  Given I don't know which build you started out with, I can only guess that, while Windows Update claims the update was installed it really wasn't.  At some point you went from March 2018 to September 2018, that update happens to have replaced, an update released in March 2018.  There simply isn't enough information to answer this question.

Comment: I didn’t skip any purposely. These updates were all installed on the same day as you can see. What I noticed is all the updates installed the same on both servers - except one had 2018-04 and the other didn’t. This is what I find to be most odd.

Comment: I believe the start build was 14393.1884